# In R, how to count observations when each observation is in a different variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which observation of one event occurs in different variables. To make a more clear example, imagine this:
4 people are told to go out in the woods and register trees. They are told to note the type of tree in the order they stumble upon them. Hence, each person hands in a list of the 1st to the 4th tree they found. It results in this data frame:

```
treedata <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Tree_1 = c("birch", "oak", 
"oak", "alder"), Tree_2 = c("oak", "sequoia", "birch", "oak"), 
    Tree_3 = c("sequoia", NA, "alder", "birch"), Tree_4 = c("alder", 
    NA, NA, "sequoia")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
4L))
```

And the data looks like this

[image]

The data scientist is then told to count the number of observation for each tree type. But the problem is that for example "birch" appears in the variable "Tree_1" for ID 1, "Tree_2 for ID 3 and "Tree_3" for ID 4.

Basically what I want to do here is transform the Tree_x variables to a "birch" variable, "oak" variable and so forth and then assign a value of Yes or No if the ID stumbled upon that tree. Besides counting the trees, the new variables will be used to correlate the trees to a numerical variable.

My first idea was to use "unite", then rearrange so that each tree comes in the same order, then create a new variable. However I did not succeed in this and since there are NAs it proved a bit difficult still.

Expected outcome:
[image]

Does anyone have a solution? I tried googling and searching SO without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `recast`

```
library(reshape2)
recast(treedata, id.var = 'ID', ID ~ value, 
   \(x) c('', 'yes')[1 + (length(x) > 0)])[-6]
```

-output

```
  ID alder birch oak sequoia
1  1   yes   yes yes     yes
2  2             yes     yes
3  3   yes   yes yes        
4  4   yes   yes yes     yes
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use the **tidyverse** packages, the first step is to transform the data to a long format that collapses the Tree columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

treedata_long <- pivot_longer(treedata, -ID, names_to = 'tree_num', values_to = 'tree_name') %>% 
  filter(!is.na(tree_name))

      ID tree_num tree_name
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    
 1     1 Tree_1   birch    
 2     1 Tree_2   oak      
 3     1 Tree_3   sequoia  
 4     1 Tree_4   alder    
 5     2 Tree_1   oak      
 6     2 Tree_2   sequoia  
 7     3 Tree_1   oak      
 8     3 Tree_2   birch    
 9     3 Tree_3   alder    
10     4 Tree_1   alder    
11     4 Tree_2   oak      
12     4 Tree_3   birch    
13     4 Tree_4   sequoia
```

Then it's simple to use the `count()` function:

```
tree_counts <- count(treedata_long, tree_name)

  tree_name     n
  <chr>     <int>
1 alder         3
2 birch         3
3 oak           4
4 sequoia       3
```

We can then use `pivot_wider` to create the presence/absence matrix in your desired output:

```
tree_wide <- treedata_long %>% 
  select(-tree_num) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = tree_name, values_from = tree_name, values_fn = \(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), 'yes', NA))

    ID birch oak   sequoia alder
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1     1 yes   yes   yes     yes  
2     2 NA    yes   yes     NA   
3     3 yes   yes   NA      yes  
4     4 yes   yes   yes     yes
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a great solution for counting the observations, which helps alot. However, I would also like to have a variable for each tree and then yes if that tree was spotted by that ID. I am sorry if I was unclear in my question. I have updated it with a desired output as suggested by akrun.

Comment: Thank you, that's much clearer. See my edits to the answer. You can also easily switch the result to "no" for missing trees by editing the `ifelse` call.

Comment: Such a neat solution to pivot_long then wide. Did not think of this. Thank you for saving me tons of time!